# Randomly Generating Number using javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried to make the combination of `6 with 5` times. Like from 1 to 6 I want to generate randomly similarly `7 to 12` and `13 to 18` upto `25 to 30`.
I tried this like

```
setInterval(function() {
  var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); //i tried from 1 to 6
    $('#my_div1').text(number);
     var number = 7 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 12); // i tried from 7 to 12
    $('#my_div2').text(number);
     var number = 13 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 18); // from 13 to 18
    $('#my_div3').text(number);
     var number = 19 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 24); //from 19 to 24
    $('#my_div4').text(number);
     var number = 25 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);  // from 25 to 30
    $('#my_div5').text(number);
  },
1000);
```

For the first one itself is working for the next i didn't get proper value. I tried this previously in php with `rand(1,5);` like that But i am not sure how to do this in javascript. Any Suggestion would be great.

Here is the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bxZ9G/5/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right. The problem is you still multiply the random generated number by the whole amount, so you performed `7 + a random number between 1 and 12` (= max 19) while you needed `7 + a random number between 1 and 6` so the right code for the number calculation is:

```
var number = 7 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
var number = 13 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
var number = 19 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
var number = 25 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
```

Edit: Not sure if you need a number between 1 and 6 or 1 and 5, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need this:

```
setInterval(function() {
  var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); //i tried from 1 to 6
    $('#my_div1').text(number);
     var number = 7 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); // i tried from 7 to 12
    $('#my_div2').text(number);
     var number = 13 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); // from 13 to 18
    $('#my_div3').text(number);
     var number = 19 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); //from 19 to 24
    $('#my_div4').text(number);
     var number = 25 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);  // from 25 to 30
    $('#my_div5').text(number);
  },
1000);
```

**updated the fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/bxZ9G/8/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your math is wrong. Change it like so:

```
setInterval(function() {
  var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); //i tried from 1 to 6
    $('#my_div1').text(number);
     var number = 7 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); // i tried from 7 to 12
    $('#my_div2').text(number);
     var number = 13 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); // from 13 to 18
    $('#my_div3').text(number);
     var number = 19 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); //from 19 to 24
    $('#my_div4').text(number);
     var number = 25 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);  // from 25 to 30
    $('#my_div5').text(number);
  },
1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to generate a pseudo-random number between *min* and *max*:

```
function rand(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(min + (Math.random() * max));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function:

```
// Returns a random number between min and max
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

The function was taken from [Mozilla's page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) on Math.random.
Use `Math.floor` to make it a round number.

Answer (score 1):

Abstract equation for random number in specified range should be

> Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1))

So in your case your code might look like

```
function getRandomRange(min, max) {
    return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
}
setInterval(function() {
    var number = getRandomRange(1, 6); //i tried from 1 to 6
    $('#my_div1').text(number);
    var number = getRandomRange(7, 12); // i tried from 7 to 12
    $('#my_div2').text(number);
    var number = getRandomRange(13, 18); // from 13 to 18
    $('#my_div3').text(number);
    var number = getRandomRange(19, 24); //from 19 to 24
    $('#my_div4').text(number);
    var number = getRandomRange(25, 30);  // from 25 to 30
    $('#my_div5').text(number);
}, 1000);
```

Here's the fixed fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/bxZ9G/6/**

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(function() {
    var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); //i tried from 1 to 6
    $('#my_div1').text(number);
    var number = 7 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); // i tried from 7 to 12
    $('#my_div2').text(number);
    var number = 13 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); // from 13 to 18
    $('#my_div3').text(number);
    var number = 19 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); //from 19 to 24
    $('#my_div4').text(number);
    var number = 25 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);  // from 25 to 30
    $('#my_div5').text(number);
},
1000);
```

You just need a random number between 0 to 5. You can add that to 7,13,19,25 to get random numbers in the range you need.